# Is it mandatory to name folder same as domain name for virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost, apache2

I'm learning how to create virtual hosts on apache2. I have Ubuntu 16.04 operating system. I also have WSL (Ubuntu 16.04) in Windows 10.

Now, here's what I observed when I made a virtual host on **Ubuntu OS**:

I created following VH:

```
#Did work
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xyzvk.com
ServerAlias www.xyzvk.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/xyzvk.com
</VirtualHost>

#Didn't work
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xyzvk.com
ServerAlias www.xyzvk.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/yolo
</VirtualHost>
```

and added both name and alias in **/etc/hosts**

When I accessed the url in browser. I worked fine.

Now when I changed the DocumentRoot and restarted server, and tried again, it simply didn't work. It sent me to default root, i.e., **/var/www/html**

**Using WSL**

I did the same procedures, except the hosts file, which I edited in Windows hosts file as changing in Ubuntu's hosts file didn't work (maybe because it's Windows OS).

**The things worked both way this time, irrespective of the directory name.**

So my **question** is: Is it just a convention to name folder same as domain name (if yes, what can be issues that it didn't work in Ubuntu OS) OR it's mandatory?

Answer (score 2):

It is only a convention that normally simplify the live of the sysadmin as it makes everything straightforward.

You can put any path you like in `DocumentRoot` as long as Apache has relevant rights to go there, and that the rest of the configuration is adapted to that.

When you changed your `DocumentRoot` and did not had the expected behaviour, you should study Apache logfiles to learn what happened.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably repeated many times elsewhere, but with 2.2 when defining multiple virtualhosts with the same ip:port combo you must add an additional directive "once" and "in server config" context like this in your case in order to be able to "land" in the second virtualhost:

```
NameVirtualhost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xyzvk.com
ServerAlias www.xyzvk.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/xyzvk.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xyzvk.com
ServerAlias www.xyzvk.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/yolo
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `NameVirtualHost`  is needed until Apache 2.3 and then it became deprecated. Cf http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost : "Prior to 2.3.11, NameVirtualHost was required to instruct the server that a particular IP address and port combination was usable as a name-based virtual host. In 2.3.11 and later, any time an IP address and port combination is used in multiple virtual hosts, name-based virtual hosting is automatically enabled for that address."